# splitting a datetime column into year, month and week

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to split a datetime column so that the year and the month both have their own column in a select statement output. I also want to have a column by week of the year, as opposed to specific date.

Basically, I want separate year, month, and week columns to show up in my select statement output.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx should be of use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using the [`DatePart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function as shown in the following:

```
select
  datepart(year,Mydate), 
  datepart(month,Mydate),
  datepart(week,Mydate)
From
  MyTable
```

Note: If you need to calculate the week number by [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standards then you'll need to use `datepart(iso_week,Mydate)`

You could also look at the [`DateName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) function

```
select
  datename(month,Mydate)
From
  MyTable
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way.  Use SQL Servers YEAR() and MONTH() functions. For week, I use datepart(week,Mydate) as noted by @DMK.

```
SELECT YEAR(MyDate), MONTH(MyDate), DATEPART(WEEK,Mydate) From YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
select datepart(Month,DateColumn) Mnth,datename(Month,DateColumn) MnthName,datepart(Year,DateColumn) Year1,((day(DateColumn)-1) / 7) + 1 week from dbo.Table
```