# How to convert datetime.datetime to datetime.date?

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, datetime

From my sql query I'm getting output as `datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 22, 0, 0)`

```
query = '''SELECT checkin_date FROM `table1`
WHERE checkin_date BETWEEN %s AND %s'''

cursor.execute(query,(startDate, endDate)
results = cursor.fetchall()

#results:
#[(datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 22, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 24, 0, 0))]

for res in results:
   ## When I print type I get correct result
   print(type(res[0]) ## <type 'datetime.datetime'>

   ##when I compare with another datetime.date (currentDate variable)
   if res[0] < currentDate:
   ## I get error `TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date` *which is expected*

   ## But when I use .date()
   if res[0].date() < currentDate:
   ## I get `TypeError: can't compare datetime.date to unicode`
```

I tried converting `currentDate` to `datetime.datetime`, but still doesn't work. Can't seem to figure out what's the issue here.

Comment: The whole `datetime` and `date` dealio works differently in every make and model of  database server. Please add a tag for mysql, postgresql, or whichever server you use.

Comment: I use mysql. Server version: 10.1.36-MariaDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force your query to spit out the [date format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) you want, change it to this:

```
     SELECT DATE_FORMAT(checkin_date, '%Y-%c-%d') 
       FROM table1
      WHERE DATE(checkin_date) BETWEEN %s AND %s
```

To make it able to use an index on your `checkin_date` column, change it to this.

```
     SELECT DATE_FORMAT(checkin_date, '%Y-%c-%d') 
       FROM table1
      WHERE checkin_date >= DATE(%s)
        AND checkin_date < DATE(%s) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

[splitting a datetime column into year, month and week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139460/splitting-a-datetime-column-into-year-month-and-week)

```
SELECT        Year(checkin_date), Month(Checkin_date), Day(Checkin_date), 
FORMAT(GETDATE(),'HH'), FORMAT(GETDATE(),'mm')
FROM            table1
WHERE        (CAST(checkin_date AS DATE) BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2020-01-01')
```

Note: Use 'HH' for 24 hours format and 'hh' for 12.